# Take current date in different timezone in xml in odoo

Tags: xml, datetime, odoo

How do i  take current date in different timezone in xml in odoo?

I need to use it in xml to filter record in search view based on date?

By Default i am getting date in UTC (+0000)

Answer (score 0):

Swapnesh Shah,

it will be always operating in  UTC format as those XML is evaluated on server side. You can create web module to handle this situation.

Bests